# Maximum memory utilization using "balls into bins with d-choice" problem

Tags: combinatorics

I'm trying to implement the formula for [max utilization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Balls_into_bins_problem) for my hash function with d=2 (2 buckets for every hash value to choose "less loaded" one) using the following formula:

$$
\frac{m}{n} + \frac{log(log(n))}{log(d)} + \theta(1) 
$$
But the results don't make sense... Does someone have an implementation of this?
Thanks

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What do you mean by "the results don't make sense"? Can you show your calculation?